# How to convert wbxml data to json format and viceversa?

Tags: objective-c, xml, json

How to convert wbxml data to json format.

Comment: what have you tried? Also look at improving your acceptance rating users don't like not getting recognized for there work.

Comment: If an answer is helpful, go ahead and upvote it and accept it as the answer – that way other users may want to answer your questions too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your best chance at getting a fair answer would be to try to search a bit on your own, but since I'm a nice guy, I'll give you some links.

You will need an external framework to parse the `WBXML`-data, I suggest [this one](http://wbxmllib.sourceforge.net/html/index.html). I don't really know that much about the framework, but if you are able to parse the XML-data and store it in a `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary`, you can convert it to JSON as described in Apple's [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for `NSJSONSerialization`.